# Is $X= \{ u \in H^1(\Omega \times I) \mid \int_\Omega u(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}x = 0 \text{ for a.a. $y \in I$}\}$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and let $I$ be an unbounded interval.

Let $$X= \{ u \in H^1(\Omega \times I) \mid \int_\Omega u(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}x = 0 \text{ for a.a. $y \in I$}\}$$

Is this well-defined as a Hilbert space? I think it is possible to show that it is a closed subspace of $H^1(\Omega \times I)$, but I feel like the "a.a. $y \in I$" might be problematic. Maybe it should be replaced with "for all $y \in I$".

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the kernel of a map $f:H^1(\Omega\times I)\to?$ with codomain some vector space of functions on $I$ modulo measure zero such that $f(y)=\int_\Omega u(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$ for all $y\in I$. Can you pick such a space $?$ so that this linear map is continuous?

Comment: hey I thought you meant $f:H^1(\Omega \times I) \to H^1(I)$ (defined $f(u)(y) = \int_\Omega u(x,y))$ holds for a.e $y$) but you say $f(y) = \int_\Omega u(x,y)$ (maybe a typo). If I'm right, we look at $ker(f) = \{ u \in H^1(\Omega \times I) \mid f(u) = 0 \}$ but then $ker(f) = \{u \in H^1(\Omega \times I) \mid \int_\Omega u(x,y) = 0 \;a.e.\}$. I dont't think I did it right...

Comment: No what I meant was for you to find the space I wrote «?» :-)

Comment: Ok, I thought $? = H^1(I)$. Please can you expand the hint.. I don't really follow your method :|

Comment: No, as I said, I wanted **you** to pick a codomain for the map. If you think that $H^1(I)$ works and you can prove it, then so much better!

Comment: My hint is rather obvious, really: I am merely suggesting that one way to show that a subspace is closed is to write it as the kernel of some continuous map. In your case, this means: to find a topological vector space $W$ and a continuous linear map $L:H^1(\Omega\times I)\to W$ such that the kernel of $L$ is precisely the subspace of $H^1(\Omega\times I)$ you want to prove is closed.